# Set a project default for VB.NET projects so that the default Modifiers property for controls is Private

Tags: vb.net, default, private, friend, modifier

Is it possible to set a project default for VB.NET winforms projects so that the default Modifier for controls added to winforms is Private (not Friend)?

I know there's a "modifiers" property in the properties window so I can set it for each individual control... however I would like to change the project so from now on myself and other developers have to **specifically decide to change from private**. (Which I would strongly discourage them from doing).

I believe there is no way of doing this, but on another forum a while ago someone mentioned it would be possible with an add-in (but didn't name the add-in or where to get it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible to build an addin to do this. [C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/addins11292005015631am/addins.aspx) or [VB.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/santhi.m/creatingsimpleaddinforvisualstudio.net12012005020307am/creatingsimpleaddinforvisualstudio.net.aspx)

Once you have an Addin structure set in place you can do it on a button click (create a new button for them) or try and play it off of an add item event.  I am still looking to see if I can find an event for you.